# MPGS (mastercard): How to tokenize a transaction (how to create token)?

Tags: postman, integration, payment

I'm trying to create token with MPGS.

I'm following this guide:

https://**sample-sub.domain**.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/supportedFeatures/pickAdditionalFunctionality/tokenization/tokenization.html?locale=en_US#x_tokenConfiguration

In the section "Token Operations" > "Tokenize", it says:

> You can use this operation to **create** or update a **token** by storing
>   payment details against the token. ...

I'm posting this to help people who are frustrating like me with MPGS. I faced series of issues, and pulled my hair off many times. So here's the issues I faced and how to solve them (I'm stuck with issue #4).

---

**Issue #1:** Invalid credentials.

**Fix**: Make sure you're hitting the correct URL.

https://**example-subdomain**.mastercard.com/..

https://**some.other-example**.mastercard.com/..

https://**MILLION-OTHER-POSSIBILITIES**.mastercard.com/..

Even the documentation guide link have these same sub-domains, so make sure you're hitting the correct URL, and make sure you're following the correct documentation link.

---

**Issue #2:** Invalid parameters, or server asking for parameters although you've provided them.

**Fix:** If using Postman, make sure you set the parameters in "Body" > "**raw**" as JSON, like so:

```
{
    "sourceOfFunds": {
        "provided": {
            "card": {
                "expiry": {
                    "month": "05",
                    "year": "21"
                },
                "number": "5123456789012346"
            }
        },
        "type": "CARD"
    }
}
```

---

**Issue #3:** Authorization required

**Fix:** If using Postman, click on "Authorization", set "Type" it to **Basic Auth**, for "Username" set it to **merchant.YOUR_MERCHANT_ID**, for "Password" set it to **YOUR_API_PASSWORD**

---

**Issue #4 (stuck here):** Value '9999999999999999' is invalid. Card token must not be supplied

Method: **PUT**

URL: https://**test-my.sample.gateway**.mastercard.com/api/rest/version/46/merchant/**MY_MERCHANT_ID**/token/9999999999999999

Authorization: set correctly in Authorization tab

Body > raw:

```
{
    "sourceOfFunds": {
        "provided": {
            "card": {
                "expiry": {
                    "month": "05",
                    "year": "21"
                },
                "number": "5123456789012346"
            }
        },
        "type": "CARD"
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "cause": "INVALID_REQUEST",
        "explanation": "Value '9999999999999999' is invalid. Card token must not be supplied",
        "field": "tokenid",
        "validationType": "INVALID"
    },
    "result": "ERROR"
}
```

**Q:** Not sure what to do to tokenize the transaction..?! I'm stuck with **issue #4**.

Comment: Did you find a way out because I'm stuck here too!

Comment: @AdeelSiddiqui Finally got it working just now! Super lucky you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, finally figured it out. MPGS has 2 ways to create/update tokens:

1. [Tokenization where YOU provide the token](https://eu-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/apiDocumentation/rest-json/version/latest/operation/Tokenization%3A%20%20Create%20or%20Update%20Token.html?locale=en_US) (notice: **PUT** method)
2. [Tokenization where MPGS generate the token for you](https://eu-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/apiDocumentation/rest-json/version/latest/operation/Tokenization%3A%20%20Create%20or%20Update%20Token%20(with%20system-generated%20token).html?locale=en_US) (notice: **POST** method)

They're very similar.

I got it working with the 2nd option.

**Note**: This is **POST** method !!

Method: **POST**

URL: https://**SUBDOMAIN_YOU_SHOULD_BE_USING**.mastercard.com/api/rest/version/50/merchant/**YOUR_MERCHANT_ID**/token

In postman, set Authorization (as described in the question, in **issue #3**).

Sample data to send (in postman, this should be in Body > raw):

```
{
    "sourceOfFunds": {
        "provided": {
            "card": {
                "expiry": {
                    "month": "05",
                    "year": "21"
                },
                "number": "5123456789012346"
            }
        },
        "type": "CARD"
    }
}
```

Sample response:

```
{
    "repositoryId": "1000000000002",
    "response": {
        "gatewayCode": "BASIC_VERIFICATION_SUCCESSFUL"
    },
    "result": "SUCCESS",
    "sourceOfFunds": {
        "provided": {
            "card": {
                "brand": "MASTERCARD",
                "expiry": "0521",
                "fundingMethod": "CREDIT",
                "issuer": "BANCO DEL PICHINCHA, C.A.",
                "number": "512345xxxxxx2346",
                "scheme": "MASTERCARD"
            }
        },
        "type": "CARD"
    },
    "status": "VALID",
    "token": "9717501974559694",
    "usage": {
        "lastUpdated": "2019-02-25T09:36:54.928Z",
        "lastUpdatedBy": "1015",
        "lastUsed": "2019-02-25T09:36:54.928Z"
    },
    "verificationStrategy": "BASIC"
}
```

Comment: I get  an error saying "Directly providing cardholder data is not supported. Consider using a session or token." Can you please help me?

Comment: @MLPJ MPGS is frustrating/tricky and has a lot of hidden configuration (that other party/bank has control over) that may affect the response, not to mention that some errors are not clear what is the cause. So: 1-Make sure you're hitting the correct URL and subdomain, 2-Make sure your using correct method (POST, PUT, etc), 3-Make sure you're providing the correct JSON structure and values, and if still fails, contact your bank/party for support. There is a chance that what you're trying to do is not enabled on one of the parties configuration. Read my question & answer again, that may help.

Comment: Thanks @evilReiko for the explanation

Comment: @MLPJ did u able to solve the problem.. I m also getting same . Please suggest

Comment: `{
    "error": {
        "cause": "INVALID_REQUEST",
        "explanation": "Missing parameter. Merchant is not enabled for Tokenization",
        "field": "sourceOfFunds.token",
        "validationType": "MISSING"
    },
    "result": "ERROR"
}` that's my issue I am using POST with this endpoint https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/api/rest/version/57/merchant/{merchant_id}/token

Comment: @PaulaGeorge as it's in explanation, it means tokenization feature must be enabled for your merchant, that means the bank must enable it for you, contact them.

Comment: If this error appears for you "Merchant is not enabled for Tokenization" , so you should ask your bank for enable the Tokenization for you